# Asking about fixing, and then optimising my code

Tags: discussion, code, code-review-se

I have a function that I need to alter, to allow for alternate scenarios.

At the same time however, the entire method is becoming a little bit convoluted, so it does need to be proofread, and perhaps reworked so that it can work a bit smoother.

Where should I ask this question? Here or on CodeReview?

Comment: Certainly not here.  Check out the rules/policy on CR, I don't use it..

Comment: I'd really recommend asking separate questions, but if your method really is convoluted then people on SO are going to yell at you for not providing a minimal example. But I don't know how asking for code review of an implementation you intend to make breaking feature changes to is going to fly on CR.

Comment: Posting a non-working code/request to fix on CR is a no-no. Also, SO is for practical programming problem. Just make sure that the question about fixing/altering the code to allow for alternate scenarios would be useful for future readers too.  Otherwise, your question could be not well accepted on SO either...

Comment: @AndrewT. well, it doesn't not work. It just doesn't account for a certain situation like it will do "find (a)", but it won't do "find (b)".

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why this question is getting so many downvotes (9 compared to the 4 upvotes!). This doesn't look like a scenario that would be adequately covered on either help or meta on either site, and I really don't see why anyone should be uncomfortable with the idea that, sometimes, a programming problem might encompass more than one site.

Answer (score 6):

You can ask separate questions on each site.

First, focus on getting the implementation the way you want it with a question here that includes

- your current method implementation
- your problem statement (alternate scenarios you need it to work with, any restrictions you may have, etc)
- any attempted modifications you've made to your implementation

It may help to state in your question that you're aware your code is convoluted and you intend to optimize it, but *after* you've first gotten the alternate scenarios figured out, to provide context to your readers and hopefully reduce the number of "your code is bad and you should feel bad" comments.

Once you have an implementation that satisfies your requirements you can bring that over to Code Review and ask for a proper review of something that's more complete.